# Jenkins - Declarative Pipeline - Multiple Key-Values pairs in Matrix Cell

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am building a Jenkins Declarative Pipeline.

Here's a gist of what I'm trying to do(as an arbitrary example)-

1. There is a list of platforms. I have put those in a matrix cell for readability and parallelism.
2. Each of them has an associated browser.

I want the matrix to be executed so that each Key-Values list iterates together.

For Example-

```
Platforms = ["Windows", "Mac", "Linux"]
Browsers = ["Edge", "Chrome", "Firefox"]

I want the output stages to have these pairings for (Platforms,Browsers)-
    [("Windows", "Edge"),("Mac", "Chrome"),("Linux", "Firefox")]
```

In the actual case, this list is 12 long, so I don't want to define as many stages with when directives to pair these values manually, since everything else is the same in these stages.

Is there a way to do this, or a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [`excludes`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#matrix-excludes) block to handle this, but it's not particularly pretty.

```
matrix {
  axes {
    axis {
      name 'PLATFORM'
      values 'Windows', 'Mac', 'Linux'
    }
    axis {
      name 'BROWSER'
      values 'Edge', 'Chrome', 'Firefox'
    }
  }
  excludes {
    // Exclude any pairs that have PLATFORM == Windows, BROWSER != Edge
    exclude {
      axis {
        name 'PLATFORM'
        values 'Windows'
      }
      axis {
        name 'BROWSER'
        notValues 'Edge'
      }
    }
    // repeat for each expected pair
  }
}
```

Comment: A bit late to mark this as an answer, but seems to be the prettiest way of doing this.

Comment: @ArihantJoshi in the immortal words of Adam Gontier et. al: It's not too late; it's never too late.

Answer (score 1):

I am also looking for a better way to do this in declarative pipeline. So far I've discovery the below example and solution.

You can technically wrap the scripted pipeline in a `script` block, but that defeats the purpose of declarative pipeline imo.

- [Declarative pipeline - dynamic matrix axis values](https://www.reddit.com/r/jenkinsci/comments/epjgqu/declarative_pipeline_dynamic_matrix_axis_values/)

  - [Matrix building in scripted pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2019/12/02/matrix-building-with-scripted-pipeline/)

They created an issue for it, but not sure about implementation time.

- [JENKINS-62127](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-62127)